# We can't save your rule yet because a value is missing. To set it, click the underlined text in the rule description area

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook 2016 (version is in the context menu of the task bar button), trying to get notified of emails i made a rule to move to my GitLab folder, it refuses to save due to this vague error:

> We can't save your rule yet because a value is missing. To set it,
> click the underlined text in the rule description area.

[image: Vague error message with the text above.]

There are multiple underlined items. Which is it?

I [did](https://www.reddit.com/r/Outlook/comments/3tsdiy/outlook_rule_creation_help_please/) [try](https://uitranslation.com/?term=250bc2d683a3) [Google](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_2013_release/outlook-rule-creation-error/cbcb2f33-fd57-43b0-9e85-9297e8c4db02).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried them all and GitLab, despite not being in my contacts or address lists, was prefilled and okay.

Turns out **"a sound"** and **"follow up at this time"** don't have default values.

Comment: Yup, should be obviously. We need to properly assign all the values when creating Outlook rules.

Comment: Then it would be helpful to allow setting underlined valued in the condition selection area.

Comment: Maybe you could share your idea to Outlook uservioce, then other users will could vote on it for you, Microsoft may notice it and add it in the later version. By the way, in order to close this thread, please kindly mark your own reply as answers.

Comment: @JeffYang7 Thanks for the reminder. Getting rid of the mandatory waiting period would help. I have several MS accounts i don't know the password of, and the existing question there is locked with no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution.   This is because where it says 'play a sound', you need to click on the word 'sound' and choose an audio you want to hear.   I

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is essentially what the accepted answer already says. Do not add answers to existing questions unless you have significant new information not yet present.